# Record audio using MediaPlugin and send to server using base64 - Ionic 2

Tags: audio, base64, ionic2, cordova-media-plugin

In my Ionic 2 application.
I have made a function which record audio and upload to server. I have used MediaPlugin and it can record fine, but when upload it and open it on server the file can't listen. I think it because type. So, How to convert MediaPlugin to correct base64 file for upload.

**Service class for recording**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MediaPlugin } from 'ionic-native';

export enum AudioRecorderState {
    Ready,
    Recording,
    Recorded
}

@Injectable()
export class AudioRecorder {
  mediaPlugin: MediaPlugin = null;
  state: AudioRecorderState = AudioRecorderState.Ready;

  getMediaPlugin(){
    return this.mediaPlugin;
  }

  preparedRecord(){
     this.mediaPlugin = new MediaPlugin('audio.mp3');
  }

  startRecording() {
    this.mediaPlugin.startRecord();
    this.state = AudioRecorderState.Recording;
  }

  stopRecording() {
    this.mediaPlugin.stopRecord();
    this.state = AudioRecorderState.Ready;
  }
}
```

**Function in page class which call startRecording and stopRecording**

```
 startRecording() {
    try {
      this.audioRecorder.preparedRecord();
      this.audioRecorder.startRecording();
    }
    catch (e) {
      this.showAlert('Failed');
    }
  }

  stopRecording() {
    try {
      this.audioRecorder.stopRecording();
      const media = this.audioRecorder.getMediaPlugin();

      this.base64Audio = "data:audio/mp3;base64," + media

      //Use base64Audio to Upload to Server...

    }
    catch (e) {
      this.showAlert('Could not stop recording.');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The real problem is, the `MediaPlugin` does not create an `mp3`, that's only an appearance. So you can use `wav`, `asd` or anything, the `MediaPlugin` will play it correctly. However this plugin creates a file with `aac` (on android `3gp`) extension. So you cannot play on the server because that thinks the file is an `mp3` but it's not. I have the following issue when i tried to play it with html5 `audio`.

I do not know how your server works, but if like a html5 `audio` then you should convert your file to a supported extension (`mp3`, `ogg`, `wav`), or you should use another plugin.